# reuse a method call inside Func/lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, func

First let me say I'm not sure if the title of this question makes any sense, but I'm not sure how to word my problem.

I have a class defined as

```
public static class NaturalSort<T>
```

This class has a method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, String> field)
```

Basically it performs a natural sort on some list given a Func that returns the value to sort on. I've been using this for anything that I want to do a natural sort on.

Normally I would do something like

```
sorted = NaturalSort<Thing>.sort(itemList, item => item.StringValueToSortOn)
```

Now I have a case where the value I want to sort on isn't a field of the item, but is a call to some method

Something like

```
sorted = NaturalSort<Thing>.sort(itemList, item => getValue(item))
```

Now what if I getValue returns an object instead of a string. and I need to do some conditional logic to get to my string value

```
sorted = NaturalSort<Thing>.sort(itemList, item => getValue(item).Something == null ? getValue(item).SomethingElse : getValue(item).SomeotherThing)
```

This would work, except the call to getValue is expensive and I don't want to call it 3 times. Is there some way I can call it once inside the expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, lambdas can have multiple lines of code.

```
item =>
{
  var it = getvalue(item);
  return it.Something == null ? it.SomethingElse : it.SomeotherThing;
}
```

Make sure you return a value in this syntax if using a `Func<T>` delegate, while this is handled implicitly in the short syntax, you have to do it yourself in the multi-line syntax.

Also, you should make your `Sort` method an extension method, you also don't need the type parameter on the class, simply use

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, String> field)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Femaref is 100%, i'm just wondering, why you wouldnt go with

```
sorted = NaturalSort<Thing>.sort(itemList, item => getValue(item))
         .Select(item => item.Something == null ? item.SomethingElse : item.SomeotherThing)
```

Comment: That is not valid because getValue(item) does not return a string

Comment: he wants to sort by the member of `item`, thus needs that member in the sort call.

Comment: doh. had it in my head for some reason, it was a transform for the lambda. never mind my crazy talk...